# Linux : Serial Bootloader Application for the ATtiny1616

Tags: avr, atmel, avr-gcc, atmelstudio, attiny

I am working on the ATMEL ATtiny1616 micro-controller.
I am looking for a (Linux C/Phython based) serial bootloader application to program the ATtiny1616.

Will you please help me to know, Where I can get the source code for it?

Comment: Maybe avrdude??

Comment: Have you tested it?.. Bcoz, I have read some documents related to avrdude. Please refer following link [Command line options avrdude](https://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude_4.html) : -p partno. attiny1616 does not have it's part number here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDI is another way to program the ATtiny1616. But as I said, I would like to program the ATtiny1616 using the Serial Bootloader Application.

I have found a reference link on the site of the microchip. [Serial Bootloader Application](https://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en604508)
& this application will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use [pyupdi](https://github.com/mraardvark/pyupdi) for these new tinies (ATtiny814 which has the same programming protocol).

For now, pyupdi

- Can read/write fuses
- Can write FLASH
- Can not read/verify FLASH
- Can not read/write EEPROM

Comment: UPDI will be required a separate pin (PROG/RST) connection of UART to use pyupdi. I am using a raspberry pi where I can access only one UART which is used for communication with the ATtiny1616. On another hand, the serial bootloader will provide me both functionalities by using a single UART. So I am more interested in it. will you please help me to know about this?

Comment: @shivpatil I'm sorry for very late answer. I had no time for the site for two weeks. Just now I have tested pyupdi on Raspberry Pi 3 using FT232R USB-to-uart adapter and all work fine. So you can use such adapter for either programming or communication.